# Image picker and uploader in Rails

Tags: javascript, html, css, ruby-on-rails, amazon-cloudfront

If have done some research but haven't been able to find a good solution to this problem:

I'm building a Shopify app that lets the merchant create a small design to show on the product page, the design includes an image/icon.

I want the user to be able to choose from a list of icons or upload her/his own in the form when creating/editing a design.

How is this best achieved?

I can find out how to make the upload part with active storage. But to have some existing icons for the user to pick out, is where i struggle?

The plan was to use AWS Cloudfront to store these icons, but i still struggle with the functionality of displaying and choosing icons in the form.

Any clues to how i can do this is very appreciated! :_)

Comment: Hi Daniel, Welcome to SO. Please try to include details about your effort towards solving the problem as well.

Answer (score 0):

you need to pre-populate your table via script (rake task) which uploads these images to your storage like s3 etc. what you can do is write the file names with relative path ( to make your job easy) in a file and read that file to access these images from your rake task and call the same apis to upload one image at a time. Once you have the reference store as a record in the table/model (ex: design) you should iterate over each record on the view to display the preview of each image. From there it’s only a matter of capturing user clicks(to know which image they have selected) or use some js libraries which can do the job. Hope this will give you some direction. Let me know if you need to discuss further.